# Why do I get an OAuthException when I try to filter my FB Request?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

This is for the Facebook Android SDK.

When I use

new Request(session, "me/inbox", null, HttpMethod.GET, 
                            new Request.Callback() { ....

I get the entire inbox (what it's supposed to do).

But, when I change the String to "me/inbox?fields=id,to&limit=25", I get an "OAuthException, an active access token must be used to query information about the current user".

Why does this happen? All I'm trying to do is filter the response.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. This works:

```
                final Bundle accessToken = new Bundle();
                accessToken.putString("access token", session.getAccessToken());
                new Request(session, "me/inbox?fields=id,to&limit=25", accessToken, HttpMethod.GET,
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the graph API to check your URL/Querystring
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/inbox#!/docs/graph-api
if you are digging further than what you had initially checked off for the OAuth you need to go in and check off respective items that you want access to and regenerate your access token. if you are using the Querystring you posted above; it looks like you need to adjust your querystring

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/inbox#!/docs/graph-api   this is the link to the actual "EDGE"  you are attempting to use